# Is it possible to user One-Jar without IDE?

Tags: onejar

I'm trying to find a tutorial on how to use One-Jar without eclipse, with no success. Is it possible? I have my classes and commons-io.24.jar that needs to be inside, and I am compiling in command line.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you use Maven, [this plugin](https://code.google.com/p/onejar-maven-plugin/) can be used to invoke one-JAR during the build lifecycle.